# Converting C++ function to recursive function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, optimization, dynamic-programming

I'm looking over a function and need to convert it to a dynamic programming form. But I'm having difficulty understanding the logic used in this function (what would be the base case?), the original author of this function is no longer available for questioning, I can't make heads or tails of his work and there is 0 documentation available.

Description:

This function takes in a matrix of positive integers and finds the maximum sum by
selecting one element from every column in the matrix, moving left-to-right. As you move through
the matrix column-by-column, there is a penalty to your sum depending on how you
move relative to your previous two positions. If the next row you select is between the previous two
selected rows, there is no penalty; however, there is a penalty of 2 to your sum for every row above
the maximum of the previous two or below the minimum of the previous two.

```
int calSum(int row, int cols, vector<vector<int>> inputArray, vector<int> *outputArray){

    int ans[row][cols][row];
    int index[row][cols][row];

    int firstCol[row];

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){

        firstCol[i]= inputArray[i][0] - 2*(i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<row;j++){
            int penalty;

            if(i<=j){
                penalty=0;
            }else{
                penalty= 2* (i-j);
            }

            ans[i][1][j]= inputArray[i][1] - penalty+ firstCol[j];

        }
    }

    for(int j=2;j<cols;j++){

        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){


            int nextRow= i;

            for(int k=0;k<row;k++){

                int currRow= k;
                int ind=-1;
                int maxVal= INT_MIN;
                for(int l=0;l<row;l++){

                    int prevRow=l;
                    int max1= max(prevRow, currRow);
                    int min1= min(prevRow, currRow);

                    int penalty;
                    if(nextRow<=max1&&nextRow>= min1){
                        penalty=0;
                    }else if(nextRow>max1){
                        penalty= 2*(nextRow-max1);
                    }else{
                        penalty= 2*(min1-nextRow);
                    }

                    int val= -penalty+ inputArray[i][j] + ans[k][j-1][l];
                    if(val>maxVal){
                        maxVal=val;
                        ind=l;
                    }
                }

                ans[i][j][k]=maxVal;
                index[i][j][k]=ind;

            }

        }

    }

    int max=INT_MIN;
    int x=-1;
    int y=-1;

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<row;j++){

            if(ans[i][cols-1][j]>max){
                max= ans[i][cols-1][j];
                x=i;
                y=i;
            }

        }
    }

    for(int j=cols-1;j>=2;j--) {

        outputArray->push_back(x);
        int temp=x;
        x= y;
        y= index[temp][j][y];
    }

    outputArray->push_back(x);
    outputArray->push_back(y);

    return max;

}
```

I have tried tracing the code and keep getting lost in the logic. A basic explanation of what this function is doing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? You need an explanation of how this function works? What is a "dynamic form"?

Comment: Note that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (like e.g. `ans` and `index`) are not in C++. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is something that was greatly bothering me when I was looking over the code. I know C++ does not support VLAs, yet the author used them here somehow - I chose to ignore this for now as I'm not having an issue with the code itself, I'm more concerned with figuring out the logic used in this function.

Comment: Some compilers (cough GCC cough) have it as a non-portable extension. That's why I always try to disable extension whenever possible.

Comment: The problem statement is incomplete: is there any penalty for the first two columns?

Comment: @Botje We can assume the 2 previous rows are both 1 when starting the function on the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core datastructure `ans` works as follows: `ans[i][j][k]` is the best possible path from `(k, 0)` to `(i, j)`. (Note this uses row,col notation to match the notation in the program)

If we walk the code for-loop by for-loop:

- The first for-loop calculates the score of values in the first column, taking into account that everything with row > 1 has a penalty.
- The second for-loop calculates `ans[i][1][j]`, or maximum paths up to the second column, given a starting row j and ending row i.
- The third for-loop gradually expands `ans` to the right. For every column `j > 1`, it fills in `ans[i][j][k]` by finding an l that maximizes (k, 0) to (l, j-1) to (i, j). The first part can be read from `ans[k][j-1][l]`, the last step calculated according to the rules given in the problem.

  This loop also writes the optimal choice of `l` in the `ind` datastructure, so you can reconstruct the optimal path later.
- The fourth for-loop simply finds the maximal path value and stores the ending row.
- The final for-loop reconstructs the path by retracing steps in the `ind` datastructure.